# Kafka transaction - skip one offset when the application stops and be started again

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

To be fair, I have tested it with normal kafka without transaction scheme, and it does not skip the offset when I try to rerun the ProducerTest like a lot of times.

```
object ProducerTest extends LazyLogging {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "kafka.local:9092")
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("acks", "all")
    props.put("retries", "3")
    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
    val record = new ProducerRecord[String, String]("zxc", "key", "value")
    val record2 = new ProducerRecord[String, String]("zxc", "key2", "value2")
    val record3 = new ProducerRecord[String, String]("zxc", "key3", "value3")
    producer.send(record)
    producer.send(record2)
    producer.send(record3)
    Thread.sleep(3000)
  }
}
```

But when I enable transaction on producer, it will skip one offset when the ProducerTestWithTransaction application is rerun. Like when I first started it, it has an offset of 0,1,2 then after rerun, it will be 4,5,6 which skips 3, and so on and so forth.

```
object ProducerTestWithTransaction extends LazyLogging {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "kafka.local:9092")
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("enable.idempotence", "true")
    props.put("transactional.id", "alona")
    props.put("acks", "all")
    props.put("retries", "3")
    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
    val record = new ProducerRecord[String, String]("wew", "key", "value")
    val record2 = new ProducerRecord[String, String]("wew", "key2", "value2")
    val record3 = new ProducerRecord[String, String]("wew", "key3", "value3")
    producer.initTransactions()
    try {
      producer.beginTransaction()
      producer.send(record)
      producer.send(record2)
      producer.send(record3)
      producer.commitTransaction()
    } catch {
      case e: ProducerFencedException => producer.close()
      case e: Exception => producer.abortTransaction();
    }
  }
}
```

Please enlighten me why this is happening? Is there any workaround on this to not skip an offset. Thanks!
Note: I am using kafka-clients 2.4.0 and wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Transactions insert marker events, AFAIK, which may be what you're seeing

However, in both codes, `producer.flush()` should be called in a runtime shutdown hook